# Кёрнинг между буквами `с` и `о` ужасен

Tags: дефект, дизайн

Любой текст с сочетанием "со".

> [image: скриншот]

Windows 7 x64
Google Chrome 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit)

Comment: похоже на ваши [локальные проблемы](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tx0D.png)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, у тебя вообще шрифт другой... И ты ж в линуксе?

Comment: нет, внутрь программы linux я никогда даже не пробовал забираться. *шрифт другой* — о чём я и написал в первом комментарии.

Comment: Посмотрите какой шрифт у вас выбран в браузере.

Comment: В css прописано Arial,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans-serif

Comment: @PavelMayorov, вроде `Arial`.

Comment: Попробовал все эти шрифты по-отдельности - проблем нет ни с одним. Видимо, у вас что-то с шрифтами.

Comment: @PavelMayorov правильно писать "со шрифтами"

Comment: Это где смотреть-то надо, в любом сообщении/комментарии/везде?

Comment: @alexolut, да в любом сообщении и комментарии. А может и вообще везде, в остальных местах не попадалось.

Comment: Я сейчас в 58 тоже наблюдал нечто подобное, но не так ярко выраженно. В 59.0.3071.86 [уже нормально](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNXWl.png), имхо.

Comment: Подтверждаю, на Windows 7 у Хрома кривой hint-инг между `с` и `о`.

Comment: Но опять же, это у Хрома проблемы, не у сайта.

Comment: @Arhad, проблемы браузера (тем более, самого популярного) - это проблемы сайта. Как веб-разработчик говорю.

Comment: @Qwertiy, и как, интересно, разработчик *сайта* может повлиять на криво работающий *системный компонент ОС*?

Comment: @Arhad, в css есть несколько свойств, отвечающих за отрисовку. Возможно, их можно как-то применить,

Comment: В линуксовых фоксе и хроме всё в порядке, в̶е̶н̶д̶у̶з̶я̶т̶н̶и̶к̶и̶ ̶д̶о̶л̶ж̶н̶ы̶ ̶с̶т̶р̶а̶д̶а̶т̶ь̶ ̶:̶D̶

Comment: @andreymal: Вендузятники сидят на десятке и в ус не дуют.

Comment: @VladD, у вендузятников на новой работе стоит Win7 и повлиять на это невозможно (

Comment: @Qwertiy, если поставить масштаб страницы 110%, то этот дефект исчезает (но скорее всего появляются какие-то другие)

Comment: @Андрей: Ну так они не вендузятники, а подневольные злым одминам люди. Злой одмин может хоть IE 6 всем поставить, это да.

Comment: @Андрей, 110% немного лучше, но не сильно.

Comment: @Qwertiy почему бы не обновиться до 59?

Comment: @Андрей масштабы, отличные от 100% не поддерживаются на SO. Любые проблемы в них будут отклонены.